# How to read all the sub directories and create corresponding files in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, directory

I have two main directories say, `A` and `B`. Each of them contains 100 sub directories (a1,a2,.. and b1,b2,...) with random name. Those sub directories contain a file of `XY` type. The `X` value is same for a particular sub directory say `a1` and `b1` but the `Y` value is different. I now can create a `XY` type file where `Y` will be the difference between the sub directories `Y` column only, say `Y = Y1(a1) - Y2(b1)` with a simple `awk` command or so. But I don't know how to do this with a bash loop for all the sub directories. What I want a desired script which will create directories 1, 2,.. where each of the directory will contain a `XY` type file and the `XY` type files contain `X Y(a1-b1)` in directory 1, `X Y(a2-b2)` in directory 2,.., `X Y(a100-b100)` in direcotry 100. I am quite new in bash so apologize for any trivial question.

Schematic example can be like this:
I have two main directories `A` and `B`. `A` has sub directories `0.3427/  0.3514/  0.3543/  0.3792/...` and `B` has sub directories `0.4011/  0.4014/  0.4031/  0.4357/...`.

`0.3427/` sub directory of `A` contains the data file:

```
0.00 -8.79583
50.00 -8.79621
100.00 -8.79961
150.00 -8.80721
200.00 -8.81845
250.00 -8.83271
300.00 -8.8495
```

and `0.4011`  sub directory contains the data file:

```
0.00 -8.78888
50.00 -8.78954
100.00 -8.79458
150.00 -8.80459
200.00 -8.81852
250.00 -8.83561
300.00 -8.85529
```

Now I want in directory `1` there should be a file say `data.dat` with the following data:

```
0.00 0.00695
50.00 0.00667
100.00 0.00503
150.00 0.00262
200.00 -7e-05
250.00 -0.0029
300.00 -0.00579
```

This desired `data.dat` file is just the difference of column `Y` of first sub directories of `A` and `B` which can be produce by an `awk/paste` command. Now I want the same for all the other sub directories present in the `A` and `B`. where in directory `2` the `data.dat` file should contain the difference in `Y` column of `0.3514/` of `A` and `0.4014/` of `B` and so on.

Comment: For a question like this it's sometimes easier to provide examples; what you have before and what you have afterwards.  All the words you've written are unclear on the actual task.

Comment: @Stephen: Al right, I will edit the question with examples shortly.

Comment: @Stephen: I tried to make the question a bit clear with example. Does it make sense now? sorry, for not writing properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run it in the folder containing dir A and dir B.

A=A #first dir, replace with the propper name
B=B #second dir, replace with the propper name
in_file=f #replace with propper name
out_file=data.dat

B_subs=( $(ls B | sort -n) )

i=0
cd "$A"
for d in $( ls | sort -n) ; do
    a="$d"/"$in_file"
    b=../"$B"/"${B_subs[$i]}"/"$in_file"
    ((i++))
    mkdir ../"$i"
    # the one below is not correct, but gives your results
    # join "$a" "$b" | awk '{print $1, $3-$2}' > ../"$i"/"$out_file"
    # the one below is correct
    join "$a" "$b" | awk '{print $1, $2-$3}' > ../"$i"/"$out_file"
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect answer, code is working perfectly and giving me desire outputs. Sorry, I can't upvote your answer which made my life easy.